# I need to get deleted text messages from my android phone this is majorly important please help

Tags: sms

I received threats in text messages SMS on my android phone and they have been deleted accidentally 4 weeks ago

Comment: Has the phone been in use for those 4 weeks? Did you receive other text messages in that time? If yes then the chance is next to 100% that those deleted messages have been overwritten. Even if you had shut down the phone directly after deleting the messages recovery would have been extremely problematic or even impossible. Asking you mobile network operator may be the better alternative. May be they have saved the transmitted messages.